# Upgrade from 12.04 to 16.04 breaks libstdc++

Tags: upgrade, package-management, dependencies

I upgraded my computer from 12.04 to 14.04, and then from 14.04 to 16.04. There seems to be a dependancy issue with `libstdc++` where `libstdc++-5-dev` depends on a 12.04 package and `libstdc++6` depends on a 16.04 package. Output of `apt-get -f install`:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++-5-dev : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4 is installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) but 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~12.04 is installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: gcc-5-base:i386 (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.18) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

How do I clean this mess up?

Comment: Did you turn off all your non-standard repositories/ppas before the upgrades?

Comment: I haven't used any PPA's

Comment: manually installing gcc-5-base 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4 made apt-get figure it out. I then removed gcc and reinstalled the latest.

Answer (score 2):

Manually installing gcc-5-base 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4 made apt-get figure it out. I then removed gcc and reinstalled the latest